# Cordova navbar bigger in iOS 6

Tags: ios, css, cordova, ionic-framework

Working with Cordova and Ionic at the moment and trying to make an app as backwards compatible as possible (which is going surprisingly well) except I have stumbled upon one small issue.

The navbar after iOS 7 is bigger in that it covers the background of the status bar as well, as seen below.

[image: iOS 6 vs iOS 7 navbar]

So when I load the app on a phone running iOS 6 or earlier, the status bar doesn't get resized, the whole page just gets moved down, hiding some of the content in the footer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: Is it bigger? or it's transparent? I think this is the transparent navbar in iOS7

Comment: Why would you like to implement iOS 6 compatibility? The market share of the iOS Versions below iOS 7 is at about 1.5% based on 60,637,942,830 records. (https://mixpanel.com/trends/#report/ios_8/from_date:-29,report_unit:day,to_date:0)

Comment: @JadJoubran it is bigger, apologies, the example above isn't the best example. If you colour the navbar in iOS 7 or 8 the colour of the status bar also changes, however this is no the case in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, then you need to add padding like this:

```
document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
```

This should make the navbar view correctly.

See this - http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/